# Export a configured Atlas with a Python script / command line?

Tags: qgis, python, export, atlas

I just want to export a configured Atlas (composer with Atlas option and cover layer enabled)

I tried this :

```
composerView = qgis.utils.iface.activeComposers()[0]
composition = composerView.composition()
atlas = composition.atlasComposition()
composition.setAtlasMode(QgsComposition.ExportAtlas)

atlas.beginRender()
for i in range(0,atlas.numFeatures()):
    atlas.prepareForFeature(i)
    composition.exportAsPDF('C:\xxxx\test.pdf' + str(format(i)))
atlas.endRender()
```

But nothing happens.

Have anybody a clue?

Answer (score 11):

In QGIS 3.4 (maybe 3.x in general), exporting atlas seems much more straight forward than before (at least from looking the available answers).

```
from qgis.core import  QgsApplication, QgsProject, QgsLayoutExporter
import os

def export_atlas(qgs_project_path, layout_name, outputs_folder):

    # Open existing project
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    project.read(qgs_project_path)

    print(f'Project in "{project.fileName()} loaded successfully')

    # Open prepared layout that as atlas enabled and set
    layout = project.layoutManager().layoutByName(layout_name)

    # Export atlas
    exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
    settings = QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings()
    exporter.exportToImage(layout.atlas(),outputs_folder, 'png', settings)


def main():
    # Start a QGIS application without GUI
    qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
    qgs.initQgis()

    project_path = '/path/to/project.qgs'
    output_folder = '/path/to/existing/folder/'
    layout_name = 'my_layout_name'

    export_atlas(project_path, layout_name, output_folder)

    # Close the QGIS application
    qgs.exitQgis()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Actually QgsLayoutExporter can handle even more automatically for you -- you can just use `QgsLayoutExporter.exportToImage(layout.atlas(), '/home/me/output/test','png', settings)` and it'll handle the begin/endRender calls and iteration for you!

Comment: Wow!! that's automagic! I confess I was hoping for a comment like this from you :-)

Comment: Updated the answer using  @ndawson suggestion

Comment: when I run this I get a windows error: python3. 'This application failed to start because no qt platform plugin could be initialized'

Comment: Where did you run it?

Comment: I try execulte this code but no sucess, i try excly same thing, i'm los the hope to can export atlas using comand lines

Answer (score 4):

Your script ran successfully for me in the "Python script console" of QGIS.

Inspired by [Save Print/Map QGIS composer view as PNG/PDF using Python (without changing anything in visible layout)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/164196/73088), [How to export a configurated Atlas with a python script / command line?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/272839/73088), [QGIS: Automatisation de la génération d'un Atlas avec script python](https://georezo.net/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=284842), [Search for "[qgis] standalone script" on gis stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=Relevance&q=%5bqgis%5d%20standalone%20script), [How to run a simple python script for QGIS from outside (e.g. Sublime Text)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/29597/73088), [Using PyQGIS in custom applications](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#using-pyqgis-in-custom-applications), [Generate a QGIS map PDF using python](https://gist.github.com/timlinux/486793ad61db4c1dec9d), [How to create a QGIS PDF report with a few lines of python](http://kartoza.com/en/blog/how-to-create-a-qgis-pdf-report-with-a-few-lines-of-python/), [QGIS Server Plugin Filters: Add a new request to print a specific atlas feature](https://github.com/3liz/qgis-atlasprint/blob/master/filters/atlasprintFilter.py), [QGIS export “save as image” automate with python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/213065/73088), I wrote the following `exportAtlas.py` python script:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsProject, QgsComposition
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas, QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFile, QFileInfo, QByteArray, QTextStream
from PyQt4.QtXml import QDomDocument
import os
import sys

projectPath = sys.argv[1]
renderingPath = sys.argv[2]

def printAtlas(projectPath, renderingPath):
    # Inspired by [Save Print/Map QGIS composer view as PNG/PDF using Python (without changing anything in visible layout)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/164196/73088), [How to export a configurated Atlas with a python script / command line?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/272839/73088), [QGIS: Automatisation de la génération d'un Atlas avec script python](https://georezo.net/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=284842), [Search for "[qgis] standalone script" on gis stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=Relevance&q=%5bqgis%5d%20standalone%20script), [How to run a simple python script for QGIS from outside (e.g. Sublime Text)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/29597/73088), [Using PyQGIS in custom applications](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#using-pyqgis-in-custom-applications), [Generate a QGIS map PDF using python](https://gist.github.com/timlinux/486793ad61db4c1dec9d), [How to create a QGIS PDF report with a few lines of python](http://kartoza.com/en/blog/how-to-create-a-qgis-pdf-report-with-a-few-lines-of-python/), [QGIS Server Plugin Filters: Add a new request to print a specific atlas feature](https://github.com/3liz/qgis-atlasprint/blob/master/filters/atlasprintFilter.py), [QGIS export “save as image” automate with python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/213065/73088)
    #Getting project as Qfile and the first composer of the project as a QDomElement from the .qgs
    projectAsFile = QFile(projectPath)
    projectAsDocument = QDomDocument()
    projectAsDocument.setContent(projectAsFile)
    composerAsNode = projectAsDocument.elementsByTagName("Composer").at(0)
    # Only way to convert a QDomNode to a QDomDocument root, inspired by https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/164196/73088 & [Convert QDomElement to QDomDocument and vs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18868993/535203) & read the documentation http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtextstream.html & http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qdomnode.html .
    # Using a QByteArray because QString pointer can't be passed in python and QString is not available by default in QGIS python scripts [QGIS PyQt4 missing QString class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28632169/535203)
    composerAsString = QByteArray()
    composerAsNode.save(QTextStream(composerAsString), 2)
    composerAsDocument = QDomDocument()
    composerAsDocument.setContent(composerAsString)

    #Now that we got all we can open our project
    canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
    QgsProject.instance().read(QFileInfo(projectAsFile))
    bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge(
        QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot(), canvas)
    bridge.setCanvasLayers()

    #Lets try load that composer template we just extracted
    composition = QgsComposition(canvas.mapSettings())
    composition.loadFromTemplate(composerAsDocument, {})

    atlas = composition.atlasComposition()
    composition.setAtlasMode(QgsComposition.ExportAtlas)
    print 'Found %d features to render.' % atlas.numFeatures()

    atlas.beginRender()
    for i in range(1, atlas.numFeatures()):
        print 'Rendering feature %d...' % i
        atlas.prepareForFeature(i)
        featureRenderingBasePath = os.path.join(renderingPath, str(format(i)))
        composition.exportAsPDF(featureRenderingBasePath + '.pdf')
        img = composition.printPageAsRaster(0)
        img.save(featureRenderingBasePath + '.jpg', 'jpg')
    atlas.endRender()

    #Some cleanup maybe?
    QgsProject.instance().clear()


# supply path to qgis install location
#QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True) #already set in the right place "/usr" by default

# create a reference to the QgsApplication
# setting the second argument to True enables the GUI, which we need to do
# since this is a custom application
qgs = QgsApplication([], True)

# load providers
qgs.initQgis()

printAtlas(projectPath, renderingPath)

# When your script is complete, call exitQgis() to remove the provider and
# layer registries from memory
qgs.exitQgis()
```

It can be called this way: `python exportAtlas.py '/path/to/the/project.qgs' '/path/to/the/folder/where/to/generate/images/and/pdfs/'`

I was able to launch it into a Docker container with the following command: `docker run -it --rm -v ${HOME}:/home/${USER} -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY kartoza/qgis-desktop bash` and then inside the terminal ran:

```
USER_ID=`ls -lahn /home | tail -1 | awk {'print $3'}`
GROUP_ID=`ls -lahn /home | tail -1 | awk {'print $4'}`
USER_NAME=`ls -lah /home/ | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}'`
groupadd -g $GROUP_ID qgis
useradd --shell /bin/bash --uid $USER_ID --gid $GROUP_ID $USER_NAME
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib
su $USER_NAME -c "PYTHONPATH=/usr/share/qgis/python python /home/$USER_NAME/exportAtlas.py '/path/to/the/project.qgs' '/path/to/the/folder/where/to/generate/images/and/pdfs/'"
```

The problem with this script is that it doesn't take into consideration a layer which uses the [Mask plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/mask/).

I've [fixed this in another answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/289645/73088).