# Exporting layout in standalone script with QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, layouts

I'm trying to automate map export from a QGIS project in a standalone Python script, without interface.

Many of the scripts founds are for QGIS 2.
For example the script written by @TimSutton [here](http://kartoza.com/en/blog/how-to-create-a-qgis-pdf-report-with-a-few-lines-of-python/).

Here the code:

```py
# coding=utf-8

# A simple demonstration of to generate a PDF using a QGIS project
# and a QGIS layout template.
#
# This code is public domain, use if for any purpose you see fit.
# Tim Sutton 2015

import sys
from qgis.core import (
    QgsProject, QgsComposition, QgsApplication, QgsProviderRegistry)
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas, QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
from PyQt4.QtXml import QDomDocument


gui_flag = True
app = QgsApplication(sys.argv, gui_flag)

# Make sure QGIS_PREFIX_PATH is set in your env if needed!
app.initQgis()

# Probably you want to tweak this
project_path = 'project.qgs'

# and this
template_path = 'template.qpt'

def make_pdf():
    canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
    # Load our project
    QgsProject.instance().read(QFileInfo(project_path))
    bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge(
        QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot(), canvas)
    bridge.setCanvasLayers()

    template_file = file(template_path)
    template_content = template_file.read()
    template_file.close()
    document = QDomDocument()
    document.setContent(template_content)
    composition = QgsComposition(canvas.mapSettings())
    # You can use this to replace any string like this [key]
    # in the template with a new value. e.g. to replace
    # [date] pass a map like this {'date': '1 Jan 2012'}
    substitution_map = {
        'DATE_TIME_START': 'foo',
        'DATE_TIME_END': 'bar'}
    composition.loadFromTemplate(document, substitution_map)
    # You must set the id in the template
    map_item = composition.getComposerItemById('map')
    map_item.setMapCanvas(canvas)
    map_item.zoomToExtent(canvas.extent())
    # You must set the id in the template
    legend_item = composition.getComposerItemById('legend')
    legend_item.updateLegend()
    composition.refreshItems()
    composition.exportAsPDF('report.pdf')
    QgsProject.instance().clear()


make_pdf()
```

QGIS 3 is now based on Python 3 and Qt 5 and I try to simply export a layout with a script without load / show the QGIS GUI.

Which script to use under QGIS 3?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the solution working for me. The python file must be in the same directory as the QGIS 3 project file :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
from qgis.core import (QgsProject, QgsLayoutExporter, QgsApplication)

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)

gui_flag = False
app = QgsApplication([], gui_flag)

app.initQgis()

project_path = os.getcwd() + '/project.qgz'

project_instance = QgsProject.instance()
project_instance.setFileName(project_path)
project_instance.read()

manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
layout = manager.layoutByName("my_layout") # name of the layout
# or layout = manager.layouts()[0] # first layout

exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
exporter.exportToPdf(project_instance.absolutePath() + "/layout.pdf",
                     QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())

app.exitQgis()
```

Comment: worked for me once the / was included in the qgis project file location and the output directory. Thanks!

Comment: Through this  method is possible export an ATLAS with individual maps?

Comment: Yes, you can look at this answer : https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/328168/93097