# How to export all pages to PDF from Atlas using Python script

Tags: qgis, python, atlas

I have a QGIS project with multiple layouts maps and all are configured by Atlas, I want to export to PDF all pages from Atlas in a single PDF. My code exports each page from each layout in a different PDF and after that I need to merge the PDFs for each layout. Is there some way solve this? I using QGIS 3.28

```
layouts_list = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().printLayouts()

print("Encontrou", str(len(layouts_list)), "layouts")

for layout in layouts_list:
    my_atlas = layout.atlas()
    my_atlas.beginRender()
        
    while my_atlas.next():
        name = my_atlas.currentFilename()+ ' - FOLHA ' + str(my_atlas.currentFeatureNumber())
        print('Imprime', name)
        
        
        atlas_layout = my_atlas.layout()
        print("set atlas")
        exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(atlas_layout)
        print("set exporter")
        exporter.exportToPdf(destFolder + '/' + name + '.pdf', exporter.PdfExportSettings())
```

Comment: What happens if you create the exporter before the loop and only write it out after the loop rather than inside it?

Comment: I think there is no need to loop over the altas pages, this makes the exporter for you. see for example: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/328168/87346